# Are these random numbers 'safe'

Tags: c#, random, security

I'm not asking if these are truly random. I just wanted to know if two users hit the a page at the same time can they get the same random number? I'm thinking if i run this on a multicore server will i generate the same randon number a good amount of time due to syncing or whatever other reasons?

```
public static class SBackend
{
    static Random randObj = null;
    public static void init()
    {
        randObj = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.ToBinary());
        runFirstTime();
    }

    public static long getRandomId()
    {
        long randNum = (long)randObj.Next() << 33;
        randNum |= (uint)randObj.Next() << 2;
        randNum |= (uint)randObj.Next() & 3;
        return randNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi AcidZombie, why do you need to garuantee that two people don't get the same random number?  What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?  Also are you in ASP.Net? (as you refer to pages in your question)

Comment: I was using it for two things but i realize i can use a linear value for one of the. I am currently using this to produce a logid Id. The user has a cookie with the username and a httpcookie with the loginId. If anyone can guess a specific loginId a user has they can login as them. Note this changes everytime the user logins and set to 0 on logout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible for that to generate the same numbers. The seed adds nothing (it is time based by default anyway).

Also - if it is static, you should synchronize it (`Next` is not thread-safe):

```
static readonly Random rand = new Random();
public static int NextInt32() {
    lock(rand) { return rand.Next();}
}
public static long NextInt64() {
    lock(rand) { // using your algorithm...
        long randNum = (long)rand.Next() << 33;
        randNum |= (uint)rand.Next() << 2;
        randNum |= (uint)rand.Next() & 3;
        return randNum;
    }
}
```

This can **still** generate the same number by coincidence of course...

Perhaps consider a cryptographic random number generator if entropy is important.

Comment: Even with a CSPRNG you can get the same number :)

Answer (score 3):

well, if you only use it to generate random numbers which are never same, why not use System.Guid.NewGuid()?

Comment: "never same" - well, Guid is **unlikely** to be the same; but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Well, You can't get better than unlikely with a RNG anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the lock mechanism that ensures that only one thread at the time can access the Random object.

```
 public static class ThreadSafeRandom
{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        lock (r)
        {
            return r.NextDouble();
        }
    }

    public static int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        lock (r)
        {
            return r.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in a synchronized function to generate pseudo-random numbers that only repeat themselves every `m` requests (see the article for how to write one).  Make `m` a 64-bit value, and it becomes highly unlikely that you'll ever get enough requests to repeat yourself, let alone serve the same number to two concurrent visitors.

Comment: Additionally, in a threaded environment, you can make one generator for each of the N workers, and step them by N step each time, so worker 1 uses X1, xN+1, x2N+1, ..., worker 2 uses x2, xN+2, x2N+2....  and there are no collisions and no requirement for synchronization between workers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a session number, use a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs) are only as good as the seed values that they have.  Now I see that you've defined these as static classes and static methods, so assuming that you have put proper safety in place to ensure that getRandomId() is not being called by multiple threads simultaneously, then you should be in OK shape.

However, locking the access to getRandomId will introduce a bottleneck, and won't scale infinitely as your traffic increases.

Answer (score 0):

It's always going to be a possibility that you generate the same number when you use the basic Random class.  I better approach would be to use `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` which will create cryptographically strong random values.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, yes you can have two random values be the same if the two threads ask for the random value within the same tick.

Here's another thread safe random implementation. This one uses less locks per request and is therefore faster.

```
public static class ThreadSafeRandom
{
    private static Random _global = new Random();
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random _local;

    public static int Next()
    {
        Random inst = _local;
        if (inst == null)
        {
            int seed;
            lock (_global) seed = _global.Next();
            _local = inst = new Random(seed);
        }
        return inst.Next();
    }
}
```

See ["Getting random numbers in a thread-safe way"](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx) by the Parallels team for more info.